# compile sfml with visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, sfml

I know there is some material about this topic in the internet, but I still need help with it. I want to compile my c++/sfml project, and get an .exe file I can send my friends. I have header files, cpp files, source files (txt, png), and the sfml library. how do I compile all of them? I already know how to compile std code with the '**Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt**', but my problem is the external files and the sfml files. I will also prefer to use **Cmake** instead of the command prompt.

Thank you for ANY help,
Arad.

Comment: Please explain what about the material on the internet you aren't understanding. Don't SFML have a tutorial on compiling and linking? What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: Follow [this official tutorial on how to compile SFML with CMake](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/compile-with-cmake.php). If you have a specific problem, feel free to ask a specific question here.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your project to be able to use a library, it must me ABI-compatible with it, essentially meaning it must have been compiled with the same compiler, but not necessarily at the same time. This simplifies the process, because it means you don't have to write a monster of a `CMakeLists.txt` file. Instead, this is what I recommend:

First, setup up `vcpkg`, which you can get from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg). You have to build it yourself, but it's super easy. Literally all you have to do is run the batch file. This assumes your build environment is set up properly, but you said you use the command prompt already, so I'm assuming you're good.

Once you've built vcpkg, use it to install sfml. The way vcpkg works is, it downloads the sources from the central repository and builds them for you (make sure you have both git and cmake), which you can then use from Visual Studio by integrating vcpkg. (Make sure to use the correct triplet setting when installing a library. If you're on 64 bit Windows, that would be `x64-windows`, I believe.)

**Note:** You have to first integrate vcpkg by running `vcpkg integrate install` and then adding in the location of your vcpkg toolchain file in your project's `CMakeSettings.json` file. **If you don't do these two steps, or you do them wrong, this will not work.**

Having successfully done this, you will be able to integrate SFML or any other library vcpkg provides access to.

---

For actually building your project, there are billions of tutorials for simple CMakeLists files, but I want to stress a few things. The files you will have to send your friends for them to run your project are both the SFML library dlls and your project exe. Otherwise, they will get an error when trying to run your .exe file.

I'm not sure why you don't want to use the command prompt, since it's super easy to configure and build a project like that, though. You can definitely use the CMake GUI, but unless you legitimately want to be able to have that many settings to configure (which, remember, you would have to be the one to add in that flexibility), you can just use `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -T host=x64 <src-dir> && cmake --build <src-dir> --config Release --target install` and be on your way.

---

Having given the simplest solution, if you absolutely feel like you must compile SFML yourself manually for some reason, doing so is pretty simple. Just as before, you can [get the source from Github](https://github.com/SFML/SFML) or the website, then simply configure and build it. I like using the CMake GUI first to see all the configuration options, but the old `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -T host=x64 <src-dir> && cmake --build <src-dir> --config Release --target install` will work here too.

Note that I keep passing in the `-T host=x64` option and specifying `Win64` on the generator. If you don't do this, Visual Studio will default to an x86 host. CMake will generate, pass the build command to the compiler, and blamo, you've got a library. Remember to also build the debug configuration as well, otherwise you -spoiler alert- won't be able to debug while you develop.

Comment: Thank you very much. I allready followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_uZxXFo6J0&t=3s) on youtube and compiled SFML myself, but I have few questions now: the first is what should I do with the files generated in the end of the linked video? just put their directories as i am doing with normal SFML projects in the solution properties tab? my second question is what should I write in the link tab (normaly I would type sfml-MODULE-d.lib. the third question is where to put the dll files while I am building the project, last question is how to build staticly, get rid of the dll?